# oil leaks from the breather of toyota corolla 2004

Tags: toyota, corolla

[image]I have a corolla 2004 with 380000km on the counter, recently I've observed a small oil leakage in the breather part ( near the air filter), and a ''clicking'' noise somewhere in the engine.
please what's the origin of the oil leakage and is it due to the noise?

thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Post a picture of the oil leak and the surrounding area.

Comment: the picture is posted, it depicts the area where the oil leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the pictures. It does appear to be the PCV valve hose. There's a multitude of videos on YouTube which show how to replace PCV valve.

Answer (score 0):

Where that hose is coming from isn't visible, but it does look like it's the PCV valve hose. PCV valves are cheap to buy and easy to replace, I'm guessing most people who can replace their own windshield wipers are able to do that.

You could also just clean the valve, but I personally prefer replacing them.

Comment: I'd say the root cause may be that an engine with nearly 400k kilometers on the clock may have worn piston rings and/or cylinder bores and is pressurizing the crankcase which blows more oil-laden air through the PCV system. Replacing the PCV and the rubber hoses may mask the underlying problem for a while.

Comment: @TimNevins, most people who drive cars with that high of a mileage would not hesitate to go with the $7 fix for the time being... ;)